# Include doesn't work?

Tags: php, include, require, require-once

I want to use a variable from a file in a other file but my include doesn't work. In my file `index.php` I have a switch:

```
switch ($_POST["Jaartal"]) {
    case "2010":
        $dir= "2010";
        break;
    case "2006":
        $dir= "2006";
        break;
    case "2014":
        $dir= "2014";
        break;
    default:
        $dir= "2014";
}
```

And I want to use the variable `$dir` in a other PHP document named `api.php`:

```
include 'index.php';

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$url = "http://kassiesa.home.xs4all.nl/bert/uefa/data/method4/crank2014.html";
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
print $file;
```

I want to change the `$url` at the end to `/crank".$dir.".html";`

I have tried to work with `require`, `include` and `require_once` nothing works. When I use one of them the code doesn't work anymore in my `index.php`.

I hope one of you can help me.

Comment: You haven't shown the code that includes the `include` that's giving you trouble.

Comment: changed it. I want to include at the beginning of `api.php`

Comment: Enable error reporting and/or debug your code...

Comment: *"In my file Index.php"* - Just so we're clear on this, you wrote your file is `Index.php` and you're doing `include 'index.php';` On LINUX `Index.php` and `index.php` and two *different animals* altogether. Edit: As per your edit, is "index.php", ok that's cleared up.

Comment: `$dir` is not known in the api.php. i think you can put `$dir`in a session.

Comment: Plus, `switch ($_POST["Jaartal"])` that should most likely be a GET.

Comment: try and include the `api.php` in the `index.php` instead.

Comment: Are `index.php` and `api.php` in the same directory?

Comment: `index.php` is the file usually loaded by Apache when one browses to a directory. I can see why you might include other code in it, but I can't see why you'd include it in another file. Are you sure you're doing this the right way round?

Comment: `api.php` and `index.php` are in the same directory

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything then.

Comment: Do what @Fred-ii- says. If it stops working with a simple `include`, you probably have a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: Oke I will try this thank! Will let you know if I found the error.

Comment: Plus, if you show us how you're using your code, including the syntax, could we be able to help you more. The code you say you use `/crank".$dir.".html";` that doesn't tell us much without seeing full code.

Answer (score 0):

Output the value of $dir on the page you are trying to use it to see if it has a value:

```
echo $dir;
```

If it does have a value and it is returning a 404 because the $dir value has an extra / or something (this has happened to me when I formatted strings, it's a pain).

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities here.

1. `$dir` needs to be defined outside of the switch statement, so it will remain in scope.
2. If the two files in question are not in the same directory, use the full path or change your include path.
3. Use `require` because that will cause an error that will give you more information.
4. Permissions might be an issue; its unlikely, but worth a look.